# how to change 'login_required' 's Default Redirection in django settings.py 

Tags: python, django, redirect, login-required

this is my code:

```
@login_required
def signin_complete(request):
    return render_to_response('socialauth/signin_complete.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

when i run this view , it always Redirect to `/accounts/login/?next=/`

how to change this to `/other/other`

thanks

Answer (score 2):

[settings.LOGIN_URL](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#login-url)

Answer (score 0):

```
@login_required(login_url='/other/other')
```